# Is there an equivalent of UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification on watchOS 2?

Tags: ios, watchos-2

Is there an equivalent of `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` on watchOS 2?

I'm working on porting a cache function from iOS to watchOS 2 and want to recreate the clear cache functionality, but haven't found a way to check for low memory warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent on the watch. Watch apps and extensions are terminated when a hard memory limit is exceeded.

See [Understanding Memory Usage Limits for WatchKit Apps and Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1894/_index.html) for more details.

Comment: thank you, I will read that in detail and see what I will do about the caching